# How to grab picture, description from a pasted link in iOS app

Tags: ios

I'm making an app where users can paste links to things they want to add to their collection.The idea is that for example if you find a book you want to read, you can save it to your collection by copying the link and pasting into the app. I want to go one step further (if possible) by grabbing the picture, title, description etc of the item (book in this case) from the link and display it in the user's collection.

(p.s. Facebook does this well where when you post a link to your status, it displays the info)

I'm new to development in general, not just iOS - so any tips will be helpful. Nothing is too trivial.

Comment: You need to fetch the URL and look for Open Graph tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. From the bit i know about Open Graph, I had thought that's only unique to Facebook? Am I wrong?

Comment: Open Graph is just a set of HTML tags.  What would "unique to Facebook" even mean?